# Object following the wrong part of the path

Tags: parent, path

For context yellow is doing the correct thing, the blue part should be doing the same thing but on the other end of the path but it always defaults to the same end no matter what.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. For this kind of rig, usually one take advantage of the hook modifier and tie the curve to the end object. Without addon's, you should not be able to animate the curves control point in animation, so it's usually done the othe way around: control points tied to other object via hook modifier.
To my kolowledge you can't successfully rig the objects in the way you are showing: even the yellow parts where your method seems to work, probably falls apart when you try to run the animation with the play button, because you are parenting on an animated path...

Comment: I'm getting eyestrain trying to catch the menus on a blow-up of your .gif, as they flash by. Could you just give a description of how you're expecting this rig to work, please? It would be so much easier ..